# How can I merge two objects completely?

Tags: sculpting

This is only my second sculpture in Blender, so I'm completely a beginner, and I made the body and the head from different objects, because I had to move the head, but now I would like to manipulate them together. What could I do?

Here is a picture of the sculpture:

[image]

Join doesn't work, because it's true that they can be moved as one object this way, but they are still two different objects and they aren't merged. I don't want that line between them.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a boolean modifier with Union.

[image]

Comment: This will produce bad topology, but you can fix it since this is a Dyntopo sculpt. Run over the joining seams with a normal brush on low power (`0.05`) after applying the modifier.